# A property of Rational function

Tags: functions, rational-functions

My textbook says that if $f (x)=\frac {g (x)}{h (x)} $ is a rational function of $x $ and $h(x)=0$ does not have any real root then $f (x) $ is continous and non monotonic.

$f (x) $ being continous makes sense. But how can we really say that $f (x) $ is going to be non monotonic. Well, to prove that we can try saying that $f (x) $ will always have at least one maxima or minima. But how can we prove that $f'(x)=\frac{h (x)g'(x)-g (x)h'(x)}{(h (x))^2} $ will always have a root?

I have tried to make some graphs of some functions like $f (x)=\frac {x}{x^2+x+1} $ and $f (x)=\frac {x^2+2}{x^2+8} $ and they are indeed non monotonic. But how can we say for a general case?

Comment: Do it ab absurdo it may work well

Comment: You're leaving out some hypotheses. If  $g=x$ and $h=1$ then $f$ _is_ monotonic.

Comment: Or take any monotonic polynomial function $r(x)$ and another polynomial function $s(x)$ having no real roots, then $$f(x) = \frac{r(x)s(x)}{s(x)}$$ falsify your claim.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Umm some cases do exist where this is monotonic like $g=x^3$ and $h=x^2+x+1$ . But In general, it is non monotonic for majority of functions. Even I am trying to figure out that there must be some kind of restriction like the degree of numerator must be less than or equal to denominator or something like that. But don't know till now.

Comment: @Gono Some functions like this do exist but we're talking about majority of functions. See my reply to David's comment. Maybe my textbook is missing on some conditions which need to be satisfied in order for the property to hold good.

Comment: I find it pretty hard to speak about "majority of functions" if you have infinite ones. For each function without monotonicity I can present you one with. So to take your wording: "In general" there is no regularity. Also if you claim the order of the denominator is greater or equal to the numerator, e.g. take $\frac{1}{x}$ which is monotonic as well. So actually you want to know if there are some restriction which can be made to ensure non monotonicity. But this is quite a different question. The only one I see atm is the trivial one that the numerator change it's sign.